# Attributed text with UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to use attributed text with UITextField. I have got my placeholder text customised but it's ignoring the values I set for the main text property.

```
nameTextField.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paraStyle, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)]);
```

Strangely there is also an issue in the storyboard. If I set the values on the text field it loses them as soon as I click away.

Anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to set the typingAttributes, not the attributedString.

Try this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let paraStyle: NSParagraphStyle = NSParagraphStyle()
    textField.typingAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paraStyle, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.init(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)]

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually came across typingAttributes after posting and still couldn't get it to work. I didn't realise it had to go in the textfieldDidBeginEditing delegate method. Thanks again.

Comment: This solutions seems to be working good when there is no clear button on textField. I faced the issue that when the user clears the text, it loses the attributes were set.
The solution below worked better for me.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution**:

```
textField.defaultTextAttributes = yourAttributes // call in viewDidLoad
```

@DonMag's solution works **but** causes memory usage issues and app starts to lag (a lot). So using `typingAttributes`, at some point in time, the memory usage went up and never stopped and caused the app to freeze.